# Different screen sizes and resolutions on Nexus 10 emulator

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, adb

So I'm build a Cordova app, and just like everyone else, I've run into the issue of testing on different Android screen sizes and resolutions.

Other SO answers have pointed me [here](https://plus.google.com/+AdamWPowell/posts/cz5TxuoNDfG) which looks pretty promising, except for the fact that I don't have a Nexus 10.

So my plan was to install a Nexus 10 emulator and then try out some of the commands found in the link above. The problem is that when I'm using adb, it's looking for real hardware as opposed to an emulator.

Has anyone got a way around this? Because running all possible screen sizes and resolutions in the Nexus 10 emulator would be pretty damn sweet!

Comment: What's the point of this if you don't have a nexus 10 device? the idea on your link is use just a nexus 10 because he has a nexus 10, if you don't have a nexus 10 then use different emulators with different resulutions, or even better, use genymotion

Comment: @jcesarmobile I was just trying to find the quickest way of switching between screen sizes without having to install a bunch of emulators. But genymotion is actually pretty awesome!

Comment: You can try to create a nexus 10 device on genymotion, maybe the info in your link works there

Comment: @jcesarmobile that's working like a charm, go ahead and stick that in as an answer and I'll happily accept it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't have a real nexus 10 you can use [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download) and download a nexus 10 image, it will behave like a real device and the steps in your links should work